# Fetching a json from jsp and displaing on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to fetch the values from this JSON in my java script this is coming from jsp:

```
[{
        "selectionName": "Select",
        "subSelections": [{
                "id": 4,
                "subSelectionName": "Select",
                "description": "Deepmala"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "selectionName": "week14",
        "subSelections": [{
                "id": 7,
                "subSelectionName": "1",
                "description": ""
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "selectionName": "test",
        "subSelections": [{
                "id": 6,
                "subSelectionName": "test",
                "description": ""
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "selectionName": "select",
        "subSelections": [{
                "id": 3,
                "subSelectionName": "sub-select",
                "description": "Created by Prakash"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "selectionName": "testcreate",
        "subSelections": [{
                "id": 1,
                "subSelectionName": "testcreate",
                "description": ""
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "selectionName": "by htmlwidget",
        "subSelections": [{
                "id": 5,
                "subSelectionName": "by htmlwidget",
                "description": "created by html widget"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Any suggestions? I am tring to fetch it like this:

```
function getSelection() {
  var options = "";  
  $.getJSON('../r3/selection.jsp').done(function(json) {    

  //alert(json.selectionName);
  // alert(json.subSelections);
  // options += '<option value="' + value. selectionId + '">' + value.selectionName +   '</option>';
    $.each(json.subSelections, function(index, value) {

     options += '<option value="' + value. subSelectionName + '">' + value. description + '</option>';
});

     var select = $('<select id="selection" onchange="getSubselection()"/>');   
    select.append(options);
    $(document.body).append(select); 

   }).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
   alert(' fail json  : '+error);
  }); 

}
//alert(json.selectionName);
```

// alert(json.subSelections); inside the loop gives me undefined value.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.each(json, function (key, data) {
    $.each(data.subSelections, function (index, values) {
        options += '<option value="' + values.subSelectionName + '">' + values.description + '</option>';            
    });
});

var select = $('<select id="selection" onchange="getSubselection()"/>');
select.append(options);
$('body').append(select);
```

Comment: Hi Palash,I need todisplay theses values on combo/drop box .First combobox will contain the selectionName,while the second combobox will  contain the subselection name based on the selection name.I am trying this but it fetches all the values in the subslection for .posting the code in following comment.

Comment: var options,suboptions = ""; var select = $('<select id="selection" onchange="getSelection()"/>');var subselect = $('<select id="subselection" onchange=""/>');$.getJSON('/.r3/selection.jsp').done(function(json) {   
$.each(json, function (key, data) {options += '<option value="' + data.selectionName+ '">' + data.selectionName + '</option>'; 
$.each(data.subSelections, function (index, values) {
suboptions += '<option value="' + values.id + '">' + values.subSelectionName + '</option>';}); }); select.append(options); subselect.append(suboptions);   ......

Comment: ..$(document.body).append(select);$(document.body).append(subselect);     })}

Comment: JSON coming out of the jsp(selection.jsp) is the one posted at the very begining of the question :http://jsfiddle.net/LUpq3/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LUpq3/1/ the json coming out of selection.jsp is the same as posted at the bebining of the question.@Palash Mondal